# Projection Omissions Not Working On Server

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

Projection omissions are not working on my server for find()

**This works in my test environment but not on the actual webserver**:

```
all_records = list(
  streamers[streamer].find({}, {
    'date-edited':0,
    'old-amount':0
  }).limit(max_record_limit).sort([('amount', -1)])
)
```

Instead I have to do this:

```
all_records = list(
  streamers[streamer].find().limit(max_record_limit).sort([('amount', -1)])
)
```

Does anyone know why it might be working in my PC but not on the server?

Maybe because different versions of mongodb/python?

Server is running:

> Mongo v4.4.6
> Python 3.8.10
> Flask 1.1.2
> Werkzeug 1.0.1

PC is running:

> Mongo v4.0.4
> Python 3.9.1
> Flask 1.1.2
> Werkzeug 1.0.1

The error I get on the server is 500:

"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

Answer (score 0):

So this worked....

```
  cursor = streamers[streamer].find({}, {
    'date-edited': 0,
    'old-amount': 0
  }).limit(max_record_limit).sort([('amount', -1)])

  all_records = list(cursor)
```